# after many attempts, failed. Edit ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor4.x

I'm a newbie in front-end and need to use ckeditor but with some mods
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor Example</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="text_editor"></textarea>

        <script>
            //-------------------------------------
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'text_editor' );
                  width: '70%';
            CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'Image'; 
             //-------------------------------------
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to remove 'Image' button but I couldn't.

why the code below doesn't work ?

```
CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'Image';
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'Image';`  with

```
CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'image';
CKEDITOR.removeButtons = "image";
```

If you need to remove multiple plugins, separate them with commas.

```
CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'image, spellchecker';
CKEDITOR.removeButtons = "image, spellchecker";
```

Comment: but if I need to remove more than one item it does nothing 
             //-------------------------------------           
   CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'image';
   CKEDITOR.removeButtons = "image";
             //-------------------------------------           
   CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'about';
   CKEDITOR.removeButtons = "about";
             //-------------------------------------           
   CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'spellchecker';
   CKEDITOR.removeButtons = "spellchecker";
             //-------------------------------------

Comment: CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'image, spellchecker';
CKEDITOR.removeButtons = "image, spellchecker";

Comment: Use commas to separate the plugins.

Comment: @Shranime It will make your answer even more helpful if you can add the "when need to remove multiple plugins, use commas to separate the plugins" and add an example.